# Undo/Redo with server support in ngrx 4

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

**Goal:**

Implementing undo/redo functionality with server side support in Angular 4 project. For example, deleting an item from the server must be undoable with a corresponding (create) action.

There is a component for this: https://github.com/PowToon/redux-undo-redo

I'm trying to port that component using ngrx-store 4.

**Problem:**

I'm trying to convert the middleware into meta-reducer but it doesn't seem to be an easy task. How can I call `dispatch` in ngrx meta-reducer? If I can't, how could I implement a corresponding functionality?

Middleware:
https://github.com/PowToon/redux-undo-redo/blob/master/src/createUndoMiddleware.js

Or if there is any easier way to reach my goal, what would it be?

Answer (score 3):

We are trying to accomplish something very similar, and we are using [ngrx-effects](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/effects/README.md).  We use an effect to call the API to accomplish the original action, and add a second effect to store the inverse of the original action in the state.  This way we have access to the original action's payload, and can access any part of the state if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [ngrx-undoable](https://github.com/JannicBeck/ngrx-undoable)

And especially the [async-example](https://github.com/JannicBeck/ngrx-undoable/tree/master/examples/angular/async-undoable)

**Disclaimer** I'm the author of the library